# Replacing nan with blanks in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Below is my dataframe:

```
Id,ReturnCreated,ReturnTime,TS_startTime
O108808972773560,Return Not Created,nan,2018-08-23 12:30:41
O100497888936380,Return Not Created,nan,2018-08-18 14:57:20
O109648374050370,Return Not Created,nan,2018-08-16 13:50:06
O112787613729150,Return Not Created,nan,2018-08-16 13:15:26
O110938305325240,Return Not Created,nan,2018-08-22 11:03:37
O110829757146060,Return Not Created,nan,2018-08-21 16:10:37
```

I want to replace the nan with Blanks. Tried the below code, but its not working.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.concat({k:pd.Series(v) for k, v in ordercreated.items()}).unstack().astype(str).sort_index()
df.columns = 'ReturnCreated  ReturnTime  TS_startTime'.split()
df1 = df.replace(np.nan,"", regex=True)
df1.to_csv('OrderCreationdetails.csv')
```

Kindly help me understand where i am going wrong and how can i fix the same.

Comment: Type `df.info()` to see what the type of your columns are. Then select the answer from below. If it's object, it's a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think `nan`s are strings, because `.astype(str)`. So need:

```
df1 = df.replace('nan',"")
```

Answer (score 9):

You should try  DataFrame.fillna() method

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

In your case:

```
df1 = df.fillna("")
```

should work I think

Answer (score 1):

Either you can use `df.fillna("")` (i think that will perform better) or simple replace that values with blank

```
df1 = df.replace('NaN',"")
```